# How can I convert colors within range of color to a single color?

Tags: gimp

I want to select a color in my image, tell GIMP that *"For all colors within 10% of this color, convert to this new similar color"*.

So basically, i have shades of black in an image, but I want the whole thing to be jet black. I know this can be done in other programs, but I haven't seen it done in GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the [`Tolerance`](http://akvis.com/en/photoshop-tips/filling-tools.php) parameter for the `Paint Bucket` tool in Photoshop can be tweaked to achieve what you want. The higher the tolerance value, the more similar colored pixels will be affected by the `Paint Bucket` tool.

GIMP can do this as well. In GIMP, you can achieve this by choosing the [`Bucket Fill`](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html) tool and selecting the `Fill similar colors` option for `Affected Area` and then setting an appropriate value for the the `Threshold` option.

This video explains it better:
[image: GIMP Bucket Fill tool]